# How to use select dropdown with entries/saveEntry for an entry field?

Tags: frontend, saveentry

How to use select dropdown with entries/saveEntry for an entry field?

I have an entry with a field that is another entry, which I want to update with a form:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  {{ getCsrfInput() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
  <input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ entry.id }}">
  <label>Vendor
    <select name="fields[vendor][]">
      <option>---</option>
      {% for v in craft.entries.section('vendors') %}
        <option value="{{v.id}}">{{v.title}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

This works fine, except if nothing is selected in the dropdown (`<option>---</option>`). In that case, the POST value for `fields[vendor][]` is `---`, and I get a SQL foreign key constraint error.

I have also tried `<option value="">---</option>` and `<option value="NULL">---</option>` with no better outcome.

Comment: Been a while since I've dealt with this, but I did come up with this same error. Try adding `selected="selected"` to the option. I think the issue is submitting a field with empty data. The form isn't submitted with that option selected.

Comment: @ChaseGiunta - pretty sure the `selected=selected` only affects which choice is initially selected, and nothing in the post data. In any event, it didn't help (unfortunately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this a while ago and it drove me nuts. Try adding `disabled` and `selected` attributes to your initial option in the select. So in your case `<option disabled selected>---</option>`.

Comment: This is perfect, except... once you have selected a different option there is no going back to the `---` one. Probably need javascript for that, but my problem is solved.